# Why is the index not used?

Tags: mysql, index-tuning

When I run the following querys in MySQL:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Inventory AS i WHERE i.lastModified > 1389920146804
```

or

```
SELECT i._id FROM Inventory AS i WHERE i.lastModified > 1389920146804;
```

The `EXPLANE` command will show that the index on lastModified is used.

But when I run

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory AS i WHERE i.lastModified > 1389920146804;
```

or any other query with more then two rows we got a full table scan.

Why? How can I avoid a full table scan when selecting more then one row?

Comment: If lastModified  it`s not the first column in your multiple select the index will not be used.
Create a composite index on the first column,lastmodified to use an index.

Comment: What is the storage engine of the `Inventory` table ???

Comment: Please post the table definition and preferably also your explain output so we can verify that you are correctly interpreting them.

Comment: You can go ahead and try FORCE INDEX. Like I said, I was flying blind. Sorry I couldn't help. Gotta go back to work. Removing my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index probably only contains the `lastModified` column, as well as your `_id` value as a way of finding the other column values for each row.

So if your predicate (the WHERE clause) isn't filtering your index data down to few enough rows, the effort in looking up the other details over and over is too much and it will decide that it's easier to just scan the whole table.

If your index included all the columns you were interested in, you would see an ordinary seek.

Comment: When I ran the query in a way that I only got a few hits, the query DB was using the index. Nice!